# display list data in textblock verses datagrid, sharepoint webpart

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

i'm building a silverlight webpart. i simply want to display sharepoint list data in a textblock verses a datagrid because i'm only planning to return one item from the list. i've managed to get my desired result in a datagrid but i'm not sure how to modify my code so i can display my data in a textblock.

i thought i could simple write

```
texblock1.text = projects;
```

but it throws an error.

here's the code behind in my xaml main page-------------------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace something{         

    public class Project{        
        public string Title {get; set;}        
    }     

    public partial class MainPage : UserControl    
    {        
        public string SiteUrl { get; set; }        

        private ListItemCollection _projects;        

        //private Web _web = null;        
        //private string _lastErrorMessage = null;        

        public MainPage()        
        {            

            InitializeComponent();
            ClientContext context = new ClientContext(ApplicationContext.Current.Url);
            context.Load(context.Web);
            List Projects = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("projects");
            context.Load(Projects);
            CamlQuery query = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery();

            string camlQueryXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"NameLast\" /><Value Type=\"Boolean\">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"; 

            query.ViewXml = camlQueryXml;
            _projects = Projects.GetItems(query);
            context.Load(_projects);context.ExecuteQueryAsync(new ClientRequestSucceededEventHandler(OnRequestSucceeded), null);         

        }        

        private void OnRequestSucceeded(Object sender, ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs args)        
        {            

            // This is not called on the UI thread.            
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(BindData);        
        }        

        private void BindData()        
        {            

            List<Project> projects = new List<Project>();            

            foreach (ListItem li in _projects)            

            {                

                projects.Add(new Project()                

                {                    
                    Title = li["Title"].ToString(),  
                });            

            }            

            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = projects; // must be on UI thread        
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To run code in the UI thread use code as follows:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
    //add code here to which are to be executed on the UI thread
});
```

Comment: A little bit more guidance would be appreciated! thanks for your input.